# Tricky probability question which cant be solved using exclusion?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I am confused on how to go about solving this problem-

" What is the probability that 2 people in the group have a birthday in the same month out of 
a)exactly 20 people? 
b)atleast 20 people"

I think answer to b) part is 1 using pigeon hole principle-correct me if i am wrong.

For a) part According to me principle of inclusion and exclusion will work till n=12

BUT what to do after that?

Comment: Why on earth would this work only up to $12$??? Please bother to explain this, as well as your own attempts to solve this question.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  By the pigeonhole principle, if there are $13$ or more people at least two of them must be born in the same month, so the probability is $1$.  Or have I not understood?

Comment: @lulu: Perhaps OP means **exactly** $2$ people (in particularly, since PIE is mentioned).

Comment: @barakmanos  Maybe...

Comment: Yes exactly 2 people

Comment: If it was out of 12 people the answer would have been (1-(12P12)/(12^12)) but we cant do this for 13 right?

Comment: If exactly $2$ share a month then that leaves $11$ other people and $11$ other months

Comment: What if it was 20 people to choose from @henry

Comment: Are you assuming exactly two people have birthday in one month, but 3 or more people can have birthdays in another month?  Because if not... then you can't have more than 13 people and the probability of both of those are 0.

Comment: Or do you mean if two people share a month then *only* two people share a month?  So for twenty people there are at least 8 pairs of people who share months and at most 4 people who don't.  And you can't have more than 24.  Clarification is needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is answering your question but I will just place it here anyway.

Let the set $A$ = The group of people. Such that $|A|= 20$

Let the set $B$ = Number of months. Such that $|B|=12$

The generalized pigeon-hole principle in terms of sets states that if $f:A\rightarrow B$ from finite set $A$ to finite set $B$, with $|A|= n$ and  $|B|= m$; such that $n \gt m$ then there exists at least one element in $B$ such that $f$ maps $\left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil$ elements of $A$ to it.

In your case $n =20$ and $m =12$ so $\exists$ at least $\left\lceil\frac{20}{12}\right\rceil=2$ people that have their birthday in the same month.